# Very basic comment system using domain driven design

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I don't want to make this question too broad, but with DDD there are no simple questions.

In order to learn DDD I tried to make comment system for legacy blogging system.

In the screen below is shown what I have so far (it's not all tbh, but I don't want to make it too vague).
[image]

[Image URL (original size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is3R7.jpg)

As you can see there is just one context of "Comment system". To make it work with my blogging app I have to make ACL (anti corruption layer).

I have few issues with this.

1. Which of these object should be an aggregate? I suppose that not a PostComment, so maybe I should make Post an aggregate and associate all its comments there?
2. If I want to get avatar image path of user, that is stored in legacy DB, for every comment that I get with "getPostComments" service, how can I do that? With separate query for every user?
3. Is making of separate User and Post entities a good practice for different contexts?
4. In repository implementation I have to build PostComment entity from row data, should I make a factory for it in domain layer? That factory would be used only in that implementation, so I'm not sure.

I made a PostComment entity and not just a Comment, because later I would have to add different kind of comments, like BlogComment, or CommentReply.

Thanks in advance (btw I read mr Evans book).

Comment: I am not sure if this basic system has complexity to warrant DDD, in case you are interested in a sample have a look here http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think that DDD can be used in any project (Martin Fowler wrote that if I'm not wrong). Of course there is a question if it's worth it, but it's a different issue. In this example later I would like to add nested comment, comment rating, notifications etc. so it's not that simple really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since noone answered this question yet and I have already found solutions, I'll post it here.

1. It turned out that PostComment is an aggregate, because I have a need of retrieving one PostComment (in example for increasing rating).
2. To get data of author making a comment we need to create another aggregate that will be representing Author(UL) of a comment. Which means that we also need repository for that AR.
3. Now I can say: definitely yes.
4. I'm using factory in repository implementation.